# Use php to display specific "key-value" pair from the data retrieved from the mongodb

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, database

This is the php code.

```
<?php 
// connect to mongodb
$m = new MongoClient();

// select a database
$db = $m->Example;

$collection="User";
$Query = array("Username"=>$username);
$j = $db->$collection->find($Query);   

foreach ($j as $k) {
   echo"<pre>";var_dump($k); echo"</pre>";
}

 foreach($j as $k => $v) {

       echo $k.'='.$j[$k].'<br>';

}
?>
```

In this, the data is retrieved in $j variable an when **var_dump($k)** is used the output is as follows:

```
array(8) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#6 (1) {
  ["$id"]=>
  string(24) "56d1cb49097ed3241d000029"
  }
  ["Fname"]=>
  string(4) "Ritu"
  ["Lname"]=>
  string(3) "Rad"
  ["Username"]=>
  string(4) "riri"
  ["Password"]=>
  string(4) "riri"
  ["Email"]=>
  string(23) "ritikatra@gmail.com"
}
```

But if you try to display individual key value pair as in the next foreach loop you get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array
```

How to display only a particular key and it's value?
eg:   Email    ritikatra@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Result of `\MongoCollection::find()` (your `$j`) variable is an instance of `\MongoCursor` class which implements `\Iterator` - it allows you to loop over it but it doesn't have keys (i.e. doesn't implement `\ArrayAccess`). If you want to use your results as an array you should call

```
$array = iterator_to_array($j);
```

Now you can use `$array` as it'd be plain array:

```
echo $array[0]['Email']
```